# R Version on Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

Azure Databricks currently runs R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15), which is unacceptable in my opinion since the latest R version on CRAN is 3.5.2 (2018-12-20).

My question is: Is it possible for me to upgrade and install R version 3.5.2 on Azure Databricks? Follow-up question, is there any information available regarding the release schedule for R on Databricks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got in touch with Microsoft via email and they confirmed that you cannot upgrade and install a newer version of R on Azure Databricks as R comes bundled with the Databricks runtime.

Comment: If you did it would likely break a bunch of things. The databricks runtime version includes Spark, Scala, system dependencies ( C & Fortran libraries), Python & Pyspark, R & SparkR, dbfs and interop for Azure ( or AWS) not to mention the underlying OS of each cluster node and more. There's a lot of moving parts to test together before releasing a new runtime.

Answer (score 1):

So yes you can upgrade packages yourself. To see what packages and versions are installed:

```
%sh
apt list --installed
```

Then to upgrade a package:

```
%sh
apt-get install --only-upgrade r-base
```

In my case the output of that command was:

> r-base is already the newest version (3.4.4-1xenial0).

I don't know enough about R and the versions or packages to say if that is the package you are looking for or not. But hopefully this is enough for you to find the solution.

Comment: I get the same message, but I want to install the latest release (2018-12-20, Eggshell Igloo) R-3.5.2, see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/).